# Type of Svelte Component in Typescript

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I've been trying to get the `<svelte:component />` working with Typescript with no success. This is what I have right now.

**Presentation.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let slides;
</script>

{#each slides as slide}
    <svelte:component this={slide.component} {...slide} />
{/each}
```

**+page.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import TitleSlide from '$lib/components/Slides/TitleSlide.svelte';
    import Presentation from '$lib/components/Presentation.svelte';
    import HeaderSlide from '$lib/components/Slides/HeaderSlide.svelte';

    const slides = [
        {
            component: TitleSlide,
            //
        },
        {
            component: HeaderSlide,
        }
    ]
</script>

<Presentation {slides} />
```

**TitleSlide.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import BaseSlide from './BaseSlide.svelte';

    export let title: string;
    export let subtitle: string;
</script>

<BaseSlide>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <h1 class="text-8xl font-bold">{title}</h1>
        <h2 class="text-4xl">{subtitle}</h2>
    </div>
</BaseSlide>
```

**HeaderSlide.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import BaseSlide from './BaseSlide.svelte';

    export let header: string;
</script>

<BaseSlide>
    <h3 class="text-6xl">{header}</h3>
</BaseSlide>
```

**BaseSlide.svelte**

```
<section class="flex h-screen items-center justify-center bg-slate-300">
    <slot />
</section>
```

What I want to do here is define all the slides in the slides array in `+page.svelte` with props depending on the component's type in Typescript. I've done some research and found out that components can be typed with `writable<typeof SvelteComponent>` in [this StackOverflow post](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/486) but the only import that I can find for `writable` gave me an error when I typed it as `export let slides: writable<typeof SvelteComponent>[];` I also tried `export let slides: Writable<typeof SvelteComponent>[];` but it gives an error on the import statement. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`writable`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store#writable) creates a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store), which has nothing to do with components themselves.
The type of a writable store would be `Writable<T>`.

The type of a component should just be [`ComponentType`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#types-componenttype), so the slides would be typed as:

```js
export let slides: { component: ComponentType }[]
```